# Meteor 1.3 and includes: where to declare your helpers?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm struggling to understand Meteor 1.3's include logic.

For an app I'm trying to put together, I have in /client/main.js:

```
import '../imports/startup/accounts-config.js';
import '../imports/ui/body.js';
import '../imports/ui/home.js';
import '../imports/ui/map.js';
import '../imports/ui/admin.js';
...
```

In /imports/ui/body.js, I have (I use flow router and mainLayout is the main layout, in which all other templates are rendered):

```
...
Template.mainLayout.onCreated(function mainLayoutOnCreated() {
  Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
  Meteor.subscribe('categories');
});
...
```

Then I have the following function:

```
Template.admin.helpers({
  categories() {
    return Categories.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
});
```

If I put this function in /imports/ui/body.js, I'm able to call 'categories' in the template with name 'admin'. However, when I put this function in /imports/ui/admin.js, I get a useless exception in the javascript console:

Exception in template helper: categories@http://localho...

How is it that moving the file in which this helper is declared, while still being included in the same 'main' file, results in an exception being thrown?

Comment: Need a reproductible or more clear architecture. From what I understand, you try to add a helper to the template admin, but you need to require such template. Try to add `import './admin.html'` on top of your `admin.js` file

Comment: Because I have no clue where the problem is, this could mean reproducing my whole app, which is neither desirable nor really doable. The admin template exists, hence all works fine when I declare the helper in body.js. I'm not including the file with the admin template, main.html, anywhere, as it is my understanding this gets loaded automatically by Meteor. And it does, as the app displays the templates with no problem (and the app work fine as long as I declare the helper in body.js).

Comment: when you put a file inside the `imports` directory you need to deal with all dependency manually using the `import` word. A good practice is to create the `template.js` alongside the `template.html` file. Your `main.js` imports the `template.js` and the `template.js` imports the `template.html`

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was doing in Meteor 1.2. However, that does not explain to me how explicitly importing the above helper function from body.js does result in a working app, while putting it in admin.js does not. Note that the helper is called, but returns with an error, when put in admin.js.

Comment: Also, your remark suggests to me that it might be more practical to not use imports at all and put files in the client and lib folder, like in Meteor 1.2, and to let Meteor deal with the imports. Or?

Comment: If you want to do mocha application unit test, you need to use the `imports` folder. The `imports` folder is also great because Meteor will deprecate the current global import stuff (~Meteor 1.5) - and it will a mess if you work more than 6 months on the same project : you have dependencies everywhere in every direction.  
It's not normal to have issue with imports : you have in your client folder an import into your `imports` folder, then it loads your `template.js` and the `template.js` loads your `template.html`

Comment: Yeah. This is why I was trying my hand at using imports. But it gives me this issue which does not make sense to me. If I import files as described above, how does it matter where I declare my helper to the extent that the helper is recognised to exist in both locations, but generates an error in one location.

Comment: can you try to recreate your issue to an exemple repository like this one I've created ? https://github.com/serut/meteor-coverage-app-exemple

Comment: Thanks @Ser. I'll work on that. At the moment, I've reverted back to the project setup as per Meteor 1.2. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the desired template and the templating package at the top of your `admin.js` file.

```
import {
  Template
} from 'meteor/templating';

import '.deep/admin.js';

Template.admin.helpers({
  categories() {
    return Categories.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan. So, you're saying that, even though the template is loaded anyway (as the app displays the template contents without the template being explicitly imported), I have to explicitly import it as well, correct?